# How to write this regular expression?

Tags: regex

This is a sample piece from a huge file containing formula and bio code. Some lines **starts with** the following characters:

```
Sheep"-head`ed,   // followed by some normal words 
Mon`o*car*bon"ic,  // followed by some normal words 
mon`o*car"di*an,  // followed by some normal words 
Pol`y*chro"mate,   // followed by some normal words 
sheep"cot`,     // followed by some normal words 
baad,    // followed by some normal words
```

I am new in regular expression. Now I am trying to use TPerlRegEx ([a wrapper of PCRE library](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html)). I need to extract:

```
Sheep"-head`ed,   
Mon`o*car*bon"ic,  
mon`o*car"di*an,  
Pol`y*chro"mate,  
sheep"cot`,    
baad,
```

Can you help me write a regular expression?

Many thanks.

Edit:

Thank all for help. If a normal is between them:

```
Sheep"-head`ed,   // followed by some normal words 
Mon`o*car*bon"ic,  // followed by some normal words 
New test,   //I do not want two or more than two words that end with comma.   
mon`o*car"di*an,  // followed by some normal words 
Pol`y*chro"mate,   // followed by some normal words 
sheep"cot`,     // followed by some normal words 
baad,    // I want this one word that ends with comma
```

I still want:

```
Sheep"-head`ed,   
Mon`o*car*bon"ic,  
mon`o*car"di*an,  
Pol`y*chro"mate,  
sheep"cot`,    
baad,   // I want this ONE word that ends with comma.
```

Thank you again.

Comment: Why do you need a regex?  Why not just split each line on `/\s+/`?

Comment: are the special characters in your example actually in your strings, or are they some attempt at regex syntax?

Comment: @Kip Thanks, they are real samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raw regex is `^[^,]+,` regex in perl: `/^[^,]+,/`

- `^`  matches beginning of line
- `[^ ,]+` matches as many non-commas,non-spaces as possible.
- `,`  matches the comma

Comment: Thanks so much. you are so fast. If there is a normal line with 2 or more than 2 words between them. How to do it? Please see edit. I want one word plus comma and one word that contains `,*," plus comma. Please see edit. Thank you again.

Comment: The new regex has a space in it, like this: `/^[^ ,]+,/`

Answer (score 1):

To match lines which start with a given value, the regex is:

```
/^startswith/
```

You will have to escape special characters. For example:

```
/^Sheep\"\-head\`ed,/
```

(I can never remember exactly which characters need to be escaped, but in general you can escape any non-alphabetic character even if it doesn't need it.)

For one regex to match any of your examples, you can `or` them together with `|` like this:

```
/^(Sheep\"\-head\`ed,|Mon\`o\*car\*bon\"ic,|...)/
```

Comment: thank you for letting me know  more about regular expression. but I can not split answer.